# Make a method that edits original array instead of returning a new one?

Tags: javascript

```
Array.prototype.foo = function() {
    this = [ "random", "static", "replacement" ];
}

originalArray = [ "this", "was", "here", "first" ];

originalArray.foo();

console.log( originalArray ); // [ "random", "static", "replacement" ];
```

I am wondering how to do the above.

Editing the original array by applying a method to it. So far all I think I can do is:

```
Array.prototype.foo = function() {
    var arr = [ "random", "static", "replacement" ];

    return arr;
}

originalArray = [ "this", "was", "here", "first" ];

originalArray = originalArray.foo();
```

Comment: Assignment like `xyz = ...` never modifies the object under `xyz` in JS, it just makes the `xyz` variable point to a different object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the original array, then use `push`

```
Array.prototype.foo = function() {
    this.length = 0;
    this.push( "random", "static", "replacement" );
}
```

As volune said, if the input is an array, you can use the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function.

```
Array.prototype.foo = function() {
    this.length = 0;
    var newArray = ["random", "static", "replacement"];
    this.push.apply(this, newArray);
}
```

Comment: So there really is no direct way to have a method alter the value of the 'thing' it is applied to?

Comment: You could even do ```this.push.apply(this, arguments);```

Comment: @user3387566 I don't think so, even assigning to `this` is a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks guys. I prefer this answer but I assume, because my method calculates a new array based on the original, that I will have to use a for loop to push the new array values into the original wiped one.

Comment: @user3387566 you don't need a for loop, I updated the answer based on volune's suggestion.

Comment: I didn't realise that - I thought arguments was just comma separated values. Thank you both very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.foo = function() {
    this.length = 0; //this clears the array
    this.push("random"); 
    this.push("static"); 
    this.push("replacement");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .splice() to modify the array.

```
Array.prototype.foo = function() {
    this.splice(0,this.length,"random","static","replacement");
}
```